# Easy level, selecting elements in DOM, optimization, creating method function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom, optimization

Please, do not laugh, too much. I know jQuery ans JS for a short a while.

1) How can I make this code more efficient? First line is how do I "select" elements, the second, line is **how** do I **prep to "select"**, **next or previous** element.

```
jQuery('code:lt('+((aktywneZdanie+1).toString())+'):gt('+((aktywneZdanie-1).toString())+')').removeClass('class2');}
aktywneZdanie=aktywneZdanie-1
```

2) I can not create a function which is working as a method. What I meant is how to change:

```
jQuery('#something').addClass('class1')
                    .removeClass('class2');
```

to something like this:

```
jQuery('#something').changeClasses();
function changeClasses(){
                         .addclass('class1');
                         .removeClass('class2');}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, why do you need a selector like that? couldn't you find something less specific to hook onto? If you must keep it when joining an number and a string, JavaScript will convert the number to string behind the scenes so you don't really need the .toString() and could do the "maths" +/-1 outside of your selector making it more readable.

**Edit**
In regards to your comment I am not really sure what you mean, you could assign a class to the "post" items and then add the unique id to a data-attribute ID. To make it simpler you could do something like this:

```
var codeLt = aktywneZdanie + 1,
codeGt = aktywneZdanie - 1;

$('code:lt(' + codeLt + '):gt(' + codeGt +')').removeClass('class2');
```

**End Edit**
And the second solution should work, all your doing is passing the dom elements found from your selector into a function as a jQuery "array" in which manipulate to your needs

And for your second question why not just toggle the class on and off? having a default state which reflects class one?

```
jQuery('#something').toggleClass('uberClass');
```

Or you can pass your selector to the function

```
changeClasses(jQuery('#something'));
```

Then inside you function work on the return elements.

**Edit**
Your code should work fine, but id suggest checking to make sure you have got and element to work on:

```
changeClasses(jQuery('#something'));
function changeClasses($element){ 
    if($element.length > 0) {
        $element.addClass('class1'); 
    }
}
```

**End Edit**

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer but I still have some unclear for me isuess.
Ad. 1
I can not use id to select my elements, id is reserved for id of element (like a post id) and my elements are creating dynamic, so there will be for me a lot of problems with id targeting. Same goes for tags, there would be too many of them. Is there any shorter way to select next or previous element?
Ad. 2
Will it work?
'code'changeClasses(jQuery('#something'));
function changeClasses(element){
element.addClass('class1');
}'code'

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean regarding Ad 1, you do not need to add ID's but could use classes/data attributes. The second bit of code should work fine, but if in doubt open up the console on a page with jQuery and your selector and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How can I make this code more efficient? First line is how do I "select" elements, the second, line is how do I prep to "select", next or previous element.

```
jQuery('code:lt('+((aktywneZdanie+1).toString())+'):gt('+((aktywneZdanie-1).toString())+')').removeClass('class2');}
```

aktywneZdanie=aktywneZdanie-1

I stoped creating this wierd code like this one above, instead I start using .slice() (do not forget to use .index() for arguments here), .prev(), .next(). Just those three and everything is faster and clearer. Just an example of it below. No it does not do anything logical.

```
var activeElem = jQuery('code:first');
var old Elem;
jQuery('code').slice('0',activeElem.index()).addClass('class1');
oldElem=activeElem;
activeElem=activeElem.next();
jQuery('code').slice(oldElem.index(),activeElem.index()).addClass('class1');
oldElem.toggleClass('class1');
activeElem.prev().toggleClass('class1');
```

and the second part

> 2) I can not create a function which is working as a method. What I meant is how to change:

```
jQuery('#something').addClass('class1')
                    .removeClass('class2');
```

> to something like this:

```
jQuery('#something').changeClasses();
function changeClasses(){
                         .addclass('class1');
                     .removeClass('class2');}
```

This one is still unsolved by me.